# Changing the route inside the switch, is resetting my parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component named Tasks.js which renders on the route /tasks

```
<Route path="/tasks" component={Tasks} />
```

Inside this component, I make some API CALLS and store some state and also render a react-router switch to render 2 different tabs

```
    const Tasks =()=>{
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    
           useEffect(() => {
            //api calls
          }, [])
      return (
           <Box>
             <FiltersAndOtherComponents/>
             <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from="/tasks" to="/tasks/my-overview" />
        
                <Route exact path="/tasks/my-overview"  component={MyOverview} />
                <Route exact path="/tasks/my-work/monthly/:calendarId" component={MonthlyCalendar} />
                <Route exact path="/tasks/my-work/weekly/:calendarId" component={WeeklyCalendar} />
             </Switch>
          <Box>)
    .
```

The problem is when I switch from */tasks/my-overview* to */tasks/my-work* and vice versa, the state of the component gets totally reset (the component is remounted).

How can I fix this? To switch between routes in the parent component and maintain the state

Comment: That is expected behaviour. Every route change mounts and unmounts a component, that is how react-router works.

Comment: Check this out and see if this is what you need.  I am using the latest react-router-dom and `Switch` has been removed from it. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-minsky-bj5oyw

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-the-route-inside-the-switch-is-resetting-my-parent-state-ex2bzi). This CSB includes links to all 4 routes and navigating between them keeps the `Tasks` component mounted and retains the state. Please feel free to fork this sandbox and make a more accurate representation of your code to see if you can reproduce the issue for us to inspect and debug live.

Comment: @DrewReese, Ross Thank you guys. I really appreciate it for putting the working example on the sandbox. It made me help find the real issue (which was the useQuery of React-apollo) and not the component remounting because of changing the route. 

For anyone else having the same issue, the component should save its state in the case above